# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'int'

Tags: c#, linq

I have problem with method Count() in linq question:

```
IEnumerable<BookListRecord> bookListRecord;

IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> listTeacher = new List<Tuple<string, int>>(
from b in bookListRecord
group b by b.Teacher into g
select new { g.Key, Count = g.Count()}
);
```

I get error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`<AnonymousType#1>`' to 'int'

When I use:

```
select new {g.Key, g.Count()}
```

I get error: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

How I match the count of records to the listTeacher please? Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you typed your variable as `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>>` but you're creating a anonymous type using `select new {g.Key, g.Count()}`. Change it to the following.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> listTeacher = 
                                         (from b in bookListRecord
                                          group b by b.Teacher into g
                                          select Tuple.Create( g.Key, g.Count()))
                                         .ToList()
```

Comment: You forgot to remove the `new` keyword preceding `Tuple`. Another approach would be to keep the anonymous type and then use `var` (implicit typing) for `listTeacher`. You would need `(...).ToList()` instead of `new List<...>(...)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks, updated. I hope now it is fine. and btw technically `ToList` and new `List<T>(IEnumerable)` are same.

Comment: Yes, they are the same. I meant if you retained the anonymous type, you could do `(from b in bookListRecord group b by b.Teacher into g select new { g.Key, Count = g.Count(), }).ToList()` because the type parameter to a method can be inferred (the `TSource` in the `ToList<TSource>` method is inferred). With anonymous types you cannot use `new List<XXX>(...)` because for new-object-creation expressions the type parameter `XXX` cannot be inferred (as of C# 5).